# $L^2$-Euler number

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a closed manifold, and $\tilde M$ is the universal covering.

**Q**: Can we say that $\chi(M)=L^2\chi(\tilde M)$, where $L^2\chi(\tilde M)$ denotes the alternative sum of the dimension of $L^2$-harmonic  forms on $\tilde 
 M$?

If $M$ is a closed symplectic manifold, does the above formula hold?

Comment: From Atiyah , $χ(M)=\frac{χ(\tilde M)}{|\pi_1(M)|}$ see, M. F. Atiyah. Elliptic operators, discrete groups and von Neumann algebras.
Asterisque 32-3 (1976), 43–72

Comment: @Hassan Jolany: This only works for finite groups.

Comment: I know that Atiyah defined L2-Betti numbers in terms of the heat kernel on
$\tilde M$

Comment: Yes, but your formula is not true for infinite $\pi_1M$.

Comment: @DLIN: I don't understand your last edit. The equality holds for any closed manifold, so why specifically ask for symplectic manifolds? (And, by the way, the universal covering of a closed manifold is always complete for any lifted metric, you don't need to assume that.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is well-known and easy to prove. You find a proof in Proposition 3.2 of https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~pansu/pansu_IntroToL2BettiNumbers.pdf (and in many other places).

The reason behind is the following property of von Neumann-dimension: assuming that $dim_\Gamma$ is finite for two $\Gamma$-vector spaces V and W, then for any bounded $\Gamma$-equivariant operator $L\colon V\to W$ one has $$dim_\Gamma ker(L) -dim_\Gamma ker(L^*)=dim_\Gamma V-dim_\Gamma W.$$